# System Bottom Navigation Bar overlapping my views

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

I went into a problem, when using Samsung phones (android 12), system Nav bar is overlapping my views as follows
[overlapping Nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuSTa.png)

Here is my style.xml file

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/shape_splash</item>
    </style>
```

I also tried `fitsSystemWindows` property to set to true, but it did't work also.
Even tried `layout_marginBottom` parameter in the activity_main.xml file but still doesn't help.

What is the correct way to resolve this?

Comment: Use can try using full screen aka immersive mode.

Comment: I found out this solution in the same day I asked this Q. and it works just fine for me. Thank you